# No module named RPI error (even though it is installed)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pycharm, python-import, raspberry-pi-zero

I have recently installed RPi.GPIO into my pycharm library as well as my linux operating system,  but it seems as though anytime I run a command, I receive an error that states:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/jpxso/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/Sweep.py", line 2, in 
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'RPi'

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `pip install RPi.GIPO`. If that doesn't work, then try using the `easy_install` function in the console.

Comment: It still shows the same results. What do you mean by easy_install?

Comment: @yxngkxng480 It is just another way of installing packages in python. as an example, you would use `easy_install RPi` or `easy_install RPi.GIPO`